# How to output vt100 format text to unix socket from windows in Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, command-prompt, vt100

The text will be mis-aligned if displayed in windows prompt directly.

Is there a module for converting vt100 format so that it can display normally in windows?

**UPDATE**

Environment:

```
client: telnet from windows prompt
server: unix
```

Comment: @JB.,I just updated with more info.

Comment: Your title is a question. Your contents contain a different question. You've written down what read as hurdles attempting to do *something*. But that something you're trying to do still isn't there. At least not in a form where I can understand one. If you need an answer, provide all the information, as if we weren't familiar with your situation.

Comment: @JB., my bet is OP is asking something like this: http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=38040